# How to handle post request in Rack

Tags: ruby, rack

To respond with a json response in Rack I can do something like the below. How do I return different responses depending on if the request is a GET request or a PUT request and the data that comes with the PUT request? That is, what is the idiomatic way to inspect the request from the `env` variable and handle the various cases?

```
require 'json'

class Greeter
  def call(env)
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}, [{x:"Hello World!"}.to_json]]
  end
end

run Greeter.new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the idiomatic way to do this in Rack is to wrap your `env` in a [`Rack::Request`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html#M000274) object and call `get?`, `post?`, etc.

Here's a simple example:

```
# config.ru
run(Proc.new do
  req = Rack::Request.new(env)
  response = <<-RESP
  get? #{req.get?}
  post? #{req.post?}
RESP
  [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, [response]]
end)
```

Here's how to check it out in action:

```
$ curl http://localhost:9292
    get? true
    post? false

$ curl --data "" http://localhost:9292
    get? false
    post? true
```